# Lazarus get pointer from TForm.Components

Tags: pointers, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

How to get the pointer of a TForm.Components[x]. It is a simplified version of my program to understand the context of the problem. I need to get it ONLY in this way(Using the Components list).
Thanks a lot.

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TLabel1=class(TLabel)
    public
      MyColor:TColor;
    end;

  TLabel2=class(TLabel)
    public
      myLabel1:^TLabel1;
      procedure paint;override;
      procedure Click;override;
  end;

{ TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  l1:TLabel1;
  l2:TLabel2;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

procedure TLabel2.paint;
begin
  canvas.brush.color:=clRed;
  canvas.Rectangle(0,0,width,height);
  if mylabel1<>nil then
    canvas.TextOut(0,0,myLabel1^.Caption)
  else
    canvas.TextOut(0,0,Caption);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  l1:=TLabel1.Create(self);
  l1.Parent:=self;
  l1.Left:=24;
  l1.Top:=24;
  l1.Caption:='I am L1';

  l2:=TLabel2.Create(self);
  l2.Parent:=self;
  l2.Left:=24;
  l2.Top:=64;
  l2.Caption:='I am L2';
  l2.myLabel1:=nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  freeandnil(l1);
  freeandnil(l2);
end;

procedure TLabel2.Click;
begin
  //here is where I need to understand how to get the pointer
  myLabel1:=@TLabel1(form1.Components[0]);
  invalidate;
end;

end.
```

Comment: `myLabel1 := TLabel(Form1.Components[0]);` A reference to an object is already a pointer. (BTW, your definition of `TLabel2.myLabel1 is incorrect. Instead of `myLabel:^TLabel1`, it should be just `myLabel: TLabel1;`.)

Comment: Ok, Simple is better; Thanks @KenWhite.

Comment: No need to explicitly destroy l1 and l2 in the form's OnDestroy because l1 and l2 were created with the form as owner ("self") and therefore the form will take care of their destruction.